# How can I grab the namespace of an xml in ElementTree when the xml is input as string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

SO I have a written a script that will parse xml files and turn them into pandas dataframes for later use. This works fine for when I give the input as an actual file, but if I grab the input directly from a URL request and try to load it as a string I run into the problem of not being able to grab the namespace.

If I enter it in this way

```
tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()
ns = dict([node for _, node in ET.iterparse('test.xml', events=['start-ns'])])
```

It works fine and I can grab a dict with the namespaces. However when I grab it directly from a url and get the root like this

```
root = ET.fromstring(string_from_url)
```

It does not work since the ET.iterparse method only takes a file as an input. I know that grabbing the namespace is a seperate process from getting the xml into root but I just thought I'd include to show what is the cause of the problem.

So the question is, how can I get the namespaces when I only have a string as input?

Comment: *"I run into the problem of not being able to grab the namespace"* I don't understand that part. You should know the namespace URI *ahead of time* when dealing with XML, not "grab it" from the XML source.

Comment: Well that might be the case but this is the only way for this tool to be dynamic, since the xmls are produced elsewhere

Comment: Are the URIs the same? Because it does not matter at all what the prefixes are as long as the URIs are equal between documents. Can you make a few samples of your expected inputs & tell how you are using them?

Comment: I cannot give out the samples unfortunately, they are not public. The URIs are potentially different between the documents so that is essentially the gist of my problems. If this can be fixed as described it would solve my issue and otherwise I will have to make a work around

Comment: lxml allows you to get the namespaces via `root.nsmap`:  https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#nsmap

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for!